# how do i capture the contents of a QML webview

Tags: c++, qt, qml, thumbnails, html

I am trying to create a thumbnail of a webpage in the background of my application. The problem is that the "webkitwidgets" module is not supported on android, meaning I cannot use QWebView. So the (only?) alternative seems to be the webview from QML.

I would like to run the webview in the background while taking a picture of the frame and save it to disk so I can use it as a thumbnail preview for certain items.

I have been searching high and low on this subject, so some help would be greatly apreciated.

**The question is: How would I capture the contents of the QML webview?**
Either taking a picture of the frame or getting the source HTML from the page would suffice.

Comment: QtWebEngine is not supported on Android. See: http://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine#5405d8a903c83e89cb649f1b518ef1be

Comment: @Nejat Oh, excuse me! I thought the QML webview was from the QtWebEngine. I fixxed the post